# PHP-FPM status page on Plesk + NGINX proxy

Tags: php, apache, nginx, proxy, plesk

I am trying to enable the PHP-FPM status page on a vhost running under Plesk 17 using apache to serve PHP files, but with nginx as a proxy.
I have enabled the status page for php, but I am having trouble with the nginx rules. Here is my additional nginx directives so far

```
location /fpm-status {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/vhosts/system/fifthelement.gr/php-fpm.sock;
    access_log off;
    allow all;
}
```

However, this (and some other directives I tried too) does not seem to work since I am getting a "File not found" error while visiting the status page.

Has anyone managed to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the status-page expects the ports 80/443 for apache2, but in combination with Plesk, your apache2 - webserver listens on the ports 7080/7081 and nginx on the ports 80/443.

Pls. use for example

```html
<IfModule mod_status.c>
 Listen 8005
<Location /apache-status>
 SetHandler server-status
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
</Location>
 ExtendedStatus On
</IfModule>
```

inside your server.conf, httpd.conf and call the page from your SSH - command line with for example "lynx"

```html
lynx http://localhost:8005/apache-status
```

For your PHP-FPM - status - page, pls. locate the corresponding "fifthelement.gr.conf" ( example for the usage of the standart PHP5 - Handler from your vendor on your domain: "/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/fifthelement.gr.conf" ) and define inside:

```
pm.status_path = /fpm-status
```

Afterwards, modify your additional nginx directive to for example:

```html
location /fpm-status {
 include fastcgi.conf;
 allow 127.0.0.1;
 deny all;
 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/www/vhosts/system/fifthelement.gr/php-fpm.sock;
 access_log off;
 }
```

... and again, you might use "lynx" with the example - command:

```html
lynx http://localhost/fpm-status
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution works for the apache status page (which I already have enabled) and not for the PHP-FPM status page.

Comment: I edited by previous suggestion for you. Pls. report back with your test result. :-)

Comment: I had partial success, I can see the page, but all I get is a "File not found." error. The socket file is there and I checked with others as well... My log file writes `"FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream"`

Comment: You could probably solve this by adding "fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;" to the additional directive. Pls. test that and report back, so I could edit my above suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me using PLESK 17 on CentOS 7 (inside *Plesk > Websites & Domains > [yourdomainname] > Hosting Settings* I have: run PHP as **FPM application served by nginx**)

Steps to get a working /status page

1. Create/edit `/var/www/vhosts/system/[yourdomainname]/conf/php.ini` adding the following

   ```
   [php-fpm-pool-settings]
   pm.status_path = /status
   ```
2. Inside *Plesk > Websites & Domains > [yourdomainname] > Apache & nginx Settings* add to **Additional nginx directives** the following

   ```
   location ~ ^/status$ {
       allow 127.0.0.1;
       allow [yourip];
       deny all;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\\.php)(/?.+)$;
       fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
       fastcgi_pass "unix:///var/www/vhosts/system/[yourdomainname]/php-fpm.sock";
       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
   }
   ```
3. Reload Plesk PHP configuration

   ```
   /usr/local/psa/bin/php_settings -u
   ```

Then you should be able to access http://[yourdomainname]/status and http://[yourdomainname]/status?full